# Error 0x8007007a: failed to copy XmlConfig record Id

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix-extension

I'm using Wix XmlConfig to change an XML file, especially.

The following code will throw exceptions:

> SchedXmlConfig:  Error 0x8007007a: failed to copy XmlConfig record Id
>   SchedXmlConfig:  Error 0x8007007a: failed to read XmlConfig table
>   Error 25540. There was a failure while configuring XML files.

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_id"
                File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC"
                Name="id"
                Value="Date-UTC"/>

<!--<util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_logHeaderName"
                File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC"
                Name="logHeaderName"
                Value="date"/>-->

<util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_required"
                File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC"
                Name="required"
                Value="false"/>

<util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_defaultValue"   
                File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC"
                Name="defaultValue"
                Value="false"/>
```

The above code works fine without the **AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_defaultValue** Item.

But it will fail when include the **AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_selectedFields_Date_UTC_defaultValue**.

Could someone give some clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some search. Here the [post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27653605) figure out the issue is caused by the length an XmlConfig "Id".
The solution is to reduce the length of the id.
Refined code as followed.

```
    <!--<logField id="Date-UTC" logHeaderName="date" required="false" defaultValue="" />-->



  <util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC"
          File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
          Action="create"
          Node="element"
          ElementPath="/configuration/location[\[]@path='InterACT'[\]]/system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[\[]@baseFileName='InterACT'[\]]/selectedFields"
          Name="logField"
          On="install"
          Sequence="1006">

    <util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC_id"
                    File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                    ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC"
                    Name="id"
                    Value="Date-UTC"/>

    <util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC_logHeaderName"
                    File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                    ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC"
                    Name="logHeaderName"
                    Value="date"/>

    <util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC_required"
                    File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                    ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC"
                    Name="required"
                    Value="false"/>

    <util:XmlConfig Id="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC_defaultValue"
                    File="$(var.ApplicationHostConfigPath)"
                    ElementId="AdvancedLogging_InterACT_LogDefinition_Date_UTC"
                    Name="defaultValue"
                    Value="false"/>
  </util:XmlConfig>
```

Comment: For future readers.  I didn't find the exact count cutoff, I I figured out that 75 characters was too big, (ex: 
<util:XmlFile Id="xmlFileId012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345"
)
but 68 characters was ok (ex: 
<util:XmlFile Id="xmlFileId01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678"
)  Go figure.  But thanks Amiatabha for posting a followup.
so somewhere between there